# Count + IIF - Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, iif

Employees of the company are divided into categories A, B and C regardless of the division they work in (Finance, HR, Sales...)

How can I write a query (Access 2010) in order to retrieve the number of employees for each category and each division?

The final output will be an excel sheet where the company divisions will be in column A, Category A in column B, category B in column and category C in column D.

I thought an `IIF()` nested in a `COUNT()` would do the job but it actually counts the total number of employees instead of giving the breakdown by category.

Any idea?

```
SELECT
    tblAssssDB.[Division:],
    COUNT( IIF( [Category]   = "A", 1, 0 ) ) AS Count_A,
    COUNT( IIF( [Category]   = "B", 1, 0 ) ) AS Count_B,
    COUNT( IIF( [ET Outcome] = "C", 1, 0 ) ) AS Count_C
FROM
    tblAssssDB
GROUP BY
    tblAssssDB.[Division:];
```

My aim is to code a single sql statement and avoid writing sub-queries in order to calculate the values for each division.

Comment: Use `sum()` instead of `count()`

Comment: Have you looked at Crosstabs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Count` counts every non-Null value ... so you're counting 1 for each row regardless of the `[Category]` value.

If you want to stick with `Count` ...

```vb
Count(IIf([Category]="A",1,Null))
```

Otherwise switch to `Sum` ...

```vb
Sum(IIf([Category]="A",1,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` instead of `IIF`. Try this:

```
SELECT [Division:], [Category], Count([Category]) AS Category_Count
FROM tblAssssDB
GROUP BY [Division:], [Category];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Count:

```
Count(IIf([Field1]="N",1))+Count(IIf([Field2]="N",1)) ...
```

I grouped my qry and place Expression under this Count field I created. It worked for me

Answer (score -2):

```
Select count(iif(fieldname='a',1,null)) as  asde 
from [table name] 
where .....
```

Comment: Select accessed.[Division:], 
Count(IIf([Category]='A',1,null)) AS Count_A, 
Count(IIf([Category]='B',1,null)) AS Count_B, 
Count(IIf([ET Outcome]='C',1,null)) AS Count_C 
FROM tblAssssDB GROUP BY tblAssssDB.[Division:]