# Using a SUM() to a consult in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this consult in Access

```
SELECT CREDITOS.Id         AS  [Num Credito],          CREDITOS.CLIENTE            AS  [Cedula Cliente],
CLIENTES.NOMBRES           AS  [Nombres Cliente],      CLIENTES.APELLIDOS          AS  [Apellidos Cliente],
CREDITOS.FECHA_INICIAL     AS  [Fecha Inicial],        CREDITOS.FECHA_FINAL        AS  [Fecha Final],
CREDITOS.CONCEPTO          AS  [Concepto],             CREDITOS.VALOR_CREDITO      AS  [Valor],
CREDITOS.NUMERO_CUOTAS     AS  [Numero Cuotas],        CREDITOS.MONTO              AS  [Monto],
CREDITOS.PORCENTAJE        AS  [Porcentaje],           CREDITOS.UTILIDAD           AS  [Utilidad],
CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS      AS  [Valor Cuotas],         CREDITOS.EMPLEADO           AS  [Cedula Empleado],
EMPLEADOS.NOMBRES          AS  [Nombres Empleado],     EMPLEADOS.APELLIDOS         AS  [Apellidos Empleado],
Nz(t.Conteo,0)             AS  [Días de retraso]

FROM (CLIENTES 
INNER JOIN (EMPLEADOS 
INNER JOIN (CREDITOS 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT CREDITOS.Id AS Cred, Count(RECAUDOS.Id) AS Conteo
   FROM CREDITOS 
   INNER JOIN RECAUDOS
   ON(CREDITOS.Id = RECAUDOS.CREDITO 
   AND CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS = RECAUDOS.SALDO)
   GROUP BY CREDITOS.Id
)  AS t 
ON CREDITOS.Id = t.Cred) 
ON EMPLEADOS.ID = CREDITOS.EMPLEADO) 
ON CLIENTES.Id = CREDITOS.CLIENTE)
```

Here everything is okey I got exactly what I want, but now I need to add one more column to the consult `SUM(RECAUDOS.VALOR_RECAUDO)`, but when I add that before the first `FROM` I get the error `Your query does not include the specified expression 'Num Credito' as part of an aggregate function`. I think the problem is because the `INNER JOIN` with `RECAUDOS` for the `ON(CREDITOS.Id = RECAUDOS.CREDITO AND CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS = RECAUDOS.SALDO)` but is that way becaue I need count the records in the table `RECAUDOS` that match this condicion `CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS = RECAUDOS.SALDO`, but now I need the sum of all the `RECAUDOS.VALOR_RECAUDO` for every `CREDITOS.Id` even if this total is zero, please I really need help with this

Comment: No the error is telling you that the columns in the select clause are not in the group by clause, and they need to be, because by adding a sum() to the select list, this must be summarised by everything else.

Comment: What is a consult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add that new aggregate to the derived table (nested `SELECT` query in `JOIN` clause) and then reference it in outer, main query just like you did with *t.Conteo*:

```
LEFT JOIN ( 
     SELECT CREDITOS.Id AS Cred, Count(RECAUDOS.Id) AS Conteo,
            SUM(RECAUDOS.VALOR_RECAUDO) AS new_field
     FROM CREDITOS INNER JOIN RECAUDOS ON(CREDITOS.Id = RECAUDOS.CREDITO 
     AND CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS = RECAUDOS.SALDO) 
     GROUP BY CREDITOS.Id 
) AS t
```

Comment: If I do that the value of SUM() is zero and for all other rows that not match with this condision `ON(CREDITOS.Id = RECAUDOS.CREDITO AND CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS = RECAUDOS.SALDO)` is `null`, but your sugestion give me a idea, I will post now how I find the answer

Comment: Glad it worked out. Please accept if solution helped and to confirm resolution. In the end, only you know your data, so adjustments may be needed but overall this guided the structural query needs.

Answer (score 0):

The sugestion of Parfait gime me a good idea for this solution, the problem is in the subquery, most exactly in the condition of the `INNER JOIN... ON(CREDITOS.Id = RECAUDOS.CREDITO AND CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS = RECAUDOS.SALDO)` the `Sum(RECAUDOS.VALOR_RECAUDO)` I dont know why give me zero for all the rows, but I think give me null for all the values that not match the condition in the `INNER JOIN` for obius reasons... so, I leave the JOIN in this way `INNER JOIN... ON(CREDITOS.Id = RECAUDOS.CREDITO)` and now `SUM()` do his job, the problem with this is the `COUNT()`, I need the condition `CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS = RECAUDOS.SALDO` for the count and if I remove them for the JOIN `COUNT()` will "count" all the rows in `RECAUDOS` (without the condition), so I fount this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990229/count-iif-access-query/), so I replace the `Count(RECAUDOS.Id)` for `Count(IIf(CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS = RECAUDOS.SALDO, 1, Null))` and now everything go on rails, the final consult is this:

```
SELECT
CREDITOS.Id                AS  [Num Credito],          CREDITOS.CLIENTE            AS  [Cedula Cliente],
CLIENTES.NOMBRES           AS  [Nombres Cliente],      CLIENTES.APELLIDOS          AS  [Apellidos Cliente],
CREDITOS.FECHA_INICIAL     AS  [Fecha Inicial],        CREDITOS.FECHA_FINAL        AS  [Fecha Final],
CREDITOS.CONCEPTO          AS  [Concepto],             CREDITOS.VALOR_CREDITO      AS  [Valor],
CREDITOS.NUMERO_CUOTAS     AS  [Numero Cuotas],        CREDITOS.MONTO              AS  [Monto],
CREDITOS.PORCENTAJE        AS  [Porcentaje],           CREDITOS.UTILIDAD           AS  [Utilidad],
CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS      AS  [Valor Cuotas],         CREDITOS.EMPLEADO           AS  [Cedula Empleado],
EMPLEADOS.NOMBRES          AS  [Nombres Empleado],     EMPLEADOS.APELLIDOS         AS  [Apellidos Empleado],
t.Conteo                   AS  [Días de retraso],      t.[Total Recaudo]

FROM (CLIENTES 
INNER JOIN (EMPLEADOS 
INNER JOIN (CREDITOS 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT CREDITOS.Id AS Cred,
          Nz(Count(IIf(CREDITOS.VALOR_CUOTAS = RECAUDOS.SALDO,1,Null)),0) AS Conteo,
          Nz(Sum(RECAUDOS.VALOR_RECAUDO),0) AS [Total Recaudo]
   FROM CREDITOS 
   INNER JOIN RECAUDOS
   ON(CREDITOS.Id = RECAUDOS.CREDITO)
   GROUP BY CREDITOS.Id
)  AS t 
ON CREDITOS.Id = t.Cred) 
ON EMPLEADOS.ID = CREDITOS.EMPLEADO) 
ON CLIENTES.Id = CREDITOS.CLIENTE)
```