# Return Count for multiple variables in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I'm looking to write an SQL query which returns the number of values which equal 'Redeemed'. My column headers are as follows:

[image]

My query:

```
    Select
        Count(StatusendJanuary2021),
        Count(StatusendFebruary2021),
        Count(StatusendMarch2021),
        Count(StatusendApril2021)
    From
        SnowTable
    Where
        StatusendJanuary2021 = 'redeemed'
        Or
        StatusendFebruary2021 = 'redeemed'
        Or
        StatusendMarch2021 = 'redeemed'
        Or
        StatusendApril2021 = 'redeemed'
```

returns a fixed result for each month rather than the actual amounts for each month:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can restructure the query to output the correct count for 'redeemed' for each month?

Comment: You've tagged your question with both Excel and Access - please explain your use-case in more detail - how are you using Access from Excel or vice-versa?

Comment: Also, why do you have a denormalized `SnowTable`? Don't you have a normalized table with row-oriented data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In MS Access, this uses `iif()`:

```
Select sum(iif(StatusendJanuary2021 = "redeemed", 1, 0)),
       sum(iif((StatusendFebruary2021 = "redeemed", 1, 0)),
       sum(iif((StatusendMarch2021 = "redeemed", 1, 0)),
       sum(iif((StatusendApril2021 = "redeemed", 1, 0))
From SnowTable
```

Comment: Ah yes, the _great debate_ between `SUM( 1 or 0 )` vs `COUNT( x or NULL )`

Comment: btw, Access/JET _really_ doesn't like semicolons _at all_, and you might want to name your columns.

Comment: @Dai . . . No debate in my mind, particular in MS Access where you need to include the `NULL` explicitly.  Less typing.

Answer (score 0):

Even though JET/Access's SQL dialect is *frozen in time* with no real advancements beyond SQL-92 (for *shame* Microsoft!), it *does* seem to support expressions in `COUNT`, so you can use `IIF`, like so:

[Count + IIF - Access query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990229/count-iif-access-query)

```
SELECT
    COUNT( IIF( StatusendJanuary2021  = 'redeemed', 1, NULL ) ) AS Count_2021_01,
    COUNT( IIF( StatusendFebruary2021 = 'redeemed', 1, NULL ) ) AS Count_2021_02,
    COUNT( IIF( StatusendMarch2021    = 'redeemed', 1, NULL ) ) AS Count_2021_03,
    COUNT( IIF( StatusendApril2021    = 'redeemed', 1, NULL ) ) AS Count_2021_04
FROM
    SnowTable
```